# possible error in make file(UBuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, g++

```
TARGETS = client server

CL_OBJ = clientMain.o Controller.o UI.o List.o Movie.o Server.o Serializer.o
SV_OBJ = serverMain.o ServerControl.o Storage.o List.o Movie.o Serializer.o

server: $(SV_OBJ) Connection.o
    g++ -o server $(SV_OBJ) Connection.o

client: $(CL_OBJ) Connection.o
    g++ -o client $(CL_OBJ) Connection.o

clientMain.o:   clientMain.cc
    g++ -c clientMain.cc

serverMain.o:   serverMain.cc
    g++ -c serverMain.cc

Controller.o:   Controller.cc Controller.h 
    g++ -c Controller.cc

UI.o:   UI.cc UI.h 
    g++ -c UI.cc

List.o: List.cc List.h
    g++ -c List.cc

Movie.o:    Movie.cc Movie.h Data.h
    g++ -c Movie.cc

Server.o:   Server.cc Server.h Movie.h Data.h
    g++ -c Server.cc

Storage.o:  Storage.cc Storage.h Movie.h Data.h
    g++ -c Storage.cc

ServerControl.o:    ServerControl.cc ServerControl.h Data.h
    g++ -c ServerControl.cc

Serializer.o:   Serializer.cc Serializer.h
    g++ -c Serializer.cc

clean:
    rm -f $(CL_OBJ) $(SV_OBJ) client server
```

this makefile only produces server executable not client one. It's probably at the top part before client target because it produces client file if it switches the place with server target. I'm not sure what could be the culprit and appreciate much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make always builds the first target in the makefile by default, and *only* that target.  If you run `make client` it will build `client`.

Or you can introduce a new target as the first one, that depends on the ones you normally want to build; before your `server` target add:

```
.PHONY: all
all: server client
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a dummy target at the beginning:

```
all: $(TARGETS)
```

This will then make `all` the default target when you type `make` on its own (i.e. without specifying a target) and this will then result in both client and server being built.